# Why my String changes to an old input form Scanner after a try/catch block (edit: calling method again)

Tags: java, string, try-catch, java.util.scanner

I am programming java using Eclipse. I am quite new to handling exceptions, so probably there is something important that i am not seeing.

This is my code

```
public static String getString(String data, int dataType){
    String inString;
    System.out.print("Type the " + data + ": ");
    inString = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("1- " + inString);
    try
        {
            if (dataType == TYPE_INT){
            int i = Integer.parseInt(inString.trim());
            } else if (dataType == TYPE_DOUBLE)
        {
                double j = Double.parseDouble(inString.trim());
        }
        return inString;

    }
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
        System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Please enter the correct information.");
        getString(data, dataType);
    }
    System.out.println("return " + inString);
    return inString;
}
```

The String data is just what data I want from the user like "name" if i want them to "Type the name: "

Example from the console:

Type the information for the person.
Type the name: Frank
1- Frank
Type the year of birth yyyy: idk why this does not work
1- idk why this does not work
NumberFormatException: For input string: "idk why this does not work"
Please enter the correct information.
Type the year of birth yyyy: 1990
1- 1990
return idk why this does not work
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:   "idk why this does not work"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
    at fiu.cop3337_5916837.assigment2_1.Main.main(Main.java:24)

The last exception i get it because of this:
Integer.parseInt(getString("year of birth yyyy", TYPE_INT))

This is how i am calling the method.

I just dont understand why i get the "return idk why this does not work" when inString was already equal to 1990. Thanks!

Comment: In your try block you attempt to parse either an integer or a double, but you never do anything with that data after that. You still return inString as it originally was? What exactly are you trying to do in the try block?

Comment: I need to know whether it can be parsed, so when i return the String, I can parse it to the data type i need. I just did it this way so i could use 1 method to gather Strings, Integers, and Doubles that i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code if some `NumberFormatException` is encountered you are calling the `getString` method again. Additionally you are not throwing the exception, so the control moves out of the `catch` statement after calling `getString`.

So we have an outer `getString` method call which was getting executed and caused exception and an inner `getString` method call.

Both of these have there own `inString`.
The outer one is having `inString` equal to *idk why this does not work* while inner one is having *1990*.
The inner method call returns successfully as the data is valid, but outer method call still has `inString` equal to *idk why this does not work*. That'w why its printing the same value from `System.out.println("return " + inString);`

You might need to modify the `inString` inside your catch block.

```
 catch (NumberFormatException nfe)
    {
        System.out.println("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Please enter the correct information.");
        inString = getString(data, dataType);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I see now. I am calling getString() again but i am returning the inString from the first getString i called. I did the change you mentioned and everything worked great!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `getString(data, dataType);` from inside the `catch`, that method creates a new local `inString`. This new `inString` holds your `1990`. That variable is discarded when `getString` returns. The `catch` block finishes, and the original `inString` is printed.

BTW, `return`ing from inside a `try` block is usually a bad idea.

Comment: I added the return inside the try because i read that the code there would only execute if an exception was not found, but i really only did it trying to solve the issue i had. I will erase it now. Thanks for the advice.